# Save all Users in a certain Voicechat

Tags: c#, bots, discord.net

I started coding a Bot a week ago and I'm trying to make my bot save all Users in Lounge 1 (Code below) in the var. "v" and write every one of them a message. but "v" seems to stay empty. And I have an error on the word "client" (Can't use "DiscordSocketClient").

```
                    var v = client.Guilds.First(x =>
                x.Id.Equals(389484134214664193))
                .VoiceChannels.First(x =>
                x.Id.Equals(391228056779620352)).Users;

                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Convert.ToString(v));

                foreach (var u in v)
                {
                    var channel = await u.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync();
                    await Discord.UserExtensions.SendMessageAsync(u, msg2);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

1. I would avoid using single character variable names.  You will thank
   yourself later.
2. It may be helpful for you to put hard coded values in their own variable.

Here is a working example:

```
[Command("Test")]
[Alias("t")]
public async Task Test()
{
    ulong myGuildId = 389484134214664193;
    ulong myChannelId = 391228056779620352;

    var guild = Context.Client.Guilds.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == myGuildId);
    var voiceChannel = guild.Channels.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == myChannelId);
    var users = voiceChannel.Users;

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var dm = await user.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync();
        await dm.SendMessageAsync("Greetings");
    }
}
```